# How use line.rstrip() in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file using Python.
This is the file `test.txt` I'm using:

```
Hello World
My name is Will
What's your name?
```

This is the python code:

```
fhand = open('test.txt')
for line in fhand:
    line.rstrip()
    print line
```

No matter whether I use `line.rstrip()`, The output is always as following:

```
Hello World

My name is Will

What's your name?
```

How can I output without the empty line using `rstrip()` like this?

```
Hello World
My name is Will
What's your name?
```

Answer (score 9):

`line.rstrip()` does not change the old variable, it returns the stripped value of the old variable and you have to reassign it in order for the change to take effect, like:

```
line = line.rstrip()
```

Otherwise the line isn't changed and it uses the old line instead of the stripped one.

Answer (score 8):

```
 line.rstrip()
```

Here you do get the stripped string, but you are not storing the value.

Replace `line.rstrip()` with `line = line.rstrip()`

Let's see the demo:

```
>>> string = "hello    "
>>> string.rstrip()
'hello'
>>> string
'hello    '
>>> string = string.rstrip()
>>> string
'hello'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Strings in python (and other languages) are immutable, meaning once created they cannot be modified, so essentially `line.rstrip()` creates a new string instance with the stripped content.

You can set your variable to it before printing:

```
line = line.rstrip()
```

Same goes for other string functions e.g.: strip, lowercase, uppercase etc. and slicing e.g.: line[1:]

To find out what other types behave this way check out: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects